# read consecutive text lines into different variables?

Tags: bash, variables, text

I have a log file formatted like this:

```
$ cat log.txt
--
John Smith
12.34.56.78
Mon Nov 06, 2017 6:48 pm
--
Jane Doe
23.34.56.78
Mon Nov 06, 2017 6:49 pm
```

... and so on, several thousand times. Always in groups of 4 lines.

I'm trying to create a loop that can read each line into a specific variable so I can do something with it, then repeat this for each group.

This isn't working, but I hope I'm on the right track (the echos are only to check it works correctly):

```
while read separator username ip datetime; do
    echo "separator: [$separator]"
    echo "username: [$username]"
    echo "ip: [$ip]"
    echo "datetime: [$datetime]"
done < log.txt
```

How do I modify `read` to see each whole text line as a single variable? Then the next line as a different variable?

Thank you.

edit: wow, before anyone else decides that this is an "exact duplicate of an existing question", how about you read it first? It's not.

Comment: No, the things shown on that page do not match my example case. But thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while mapfile -t -n 4 blocks && ((${#blocks[@]})); do
  echo "separator: [${blocks[0]}]"
  echo "username: [${blocks[1]}]"
  echo "ip: [${blocks[2]}]"
  echo "datetime: [${blocks[3]}]"
done < log.txt
```

Comment: Ah, an array. Good idea. I've never used `mapfile` before, so now would be a good time to start. :D